# macOS Sierra scrolling behavior in Terminal is really weird

Tags: terminal, trackpad, macos

After upgrading to macOS Sierra, one of the things that bugs me is the altered scrolling behavior in Terminal, using the Trackpad.

See screencast here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUWO6-oOLoA

When scrolling using the Trackpad (second part of the video), the scrolling is *very* sensitive and jittery. There's no way to scroll just one line of text for instance.

Any insight into this behavior, or way to revert to the previous one?

Answer (score 2):

This has been bothering me all during the Sierra betas and I couldn't get anyone to address it.

The issue is that there's a minimum scrolling speed now. You can really see it if you use inertia scrolling. You let go and it slows down but then when it gets to a certain speed, it never goes slower than that. And then it stops abruptly at the same time it would have if it had been slowing down normally.

What you're seeing is a side-effect of this. And I haven't found a solution yet.

And this scrolling behavior is ONLY in Terminal as far as I can tell.

Go to bugreport.apple.com. I am filing more reports.

Comment: Would you link to your bug report?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem in Android Studio / the IntelliJ IDE (scrolling within source code). Thanks for pointing out the root cause... this is really annoying.

Comment: It's not possible to link to bug reports. They are associated with my appleid account and not visible to the rest of the world.

Comment: @KlaasNotFound I think your problem is different. I think that's related to a Java VM issue, as many Java apps seem to be impacted by this issue.

Comment: @jpayne So you're saying other changes in Sierra are causing the JVM to behave differently, which causes IntelliJ (and other JRE-based programs) to have messed-up scrolling? Because this problem, too, started right after installing Sierra... Really grateful for any hints as to how to fix this.

Comment: @KlaasNotFound see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158500 for the IntelliJ issue

Comment: @musicin3d Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to keep adding to this list ;-), but I just noticed that MS Word 2011 on a Mac (admittedly a bit old) has the _exact same problem_ stated by the OP. When you slow-scroll with the trackpad, nothing happens, upon faster scroll movements the document jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the hyper scrolling problem using the Terminal, and JetBrains IDEs.

This happens with the Magic Mouse too, I sent a bug report to Apple, and downgraded to OS X El Capitan, as long as they don't fix the problem in Sierra I will stay with El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug to you a few months back. I tried again today, and scrolling seems to work fine again.

I'm on Sierra Version 10.12.3 (16D32), Terminal Version 2.7.1 (388). I was using iTerm2 in the interim, but have now switched back.